# How to add gif icon to Progress Dialog setIcon using Glide?

Tags: android, android-glide, android-dialog

I'm trying to add gif icon to Progress dialog setIcon using Glide. But getting error not able resolve. This is my code.

```
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
pDialog.setTitle("Loading...");
pDialog.setIcon(Glide.with(this).asGif().load(R.drawable.loading_file));
pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
pDialog.show();
```

I'm newbie to Glide.

Comment: make a custom view and apply it to the progress dialog it will solve your problem. the reason that it don't work is setIcon() does not take glide as input

Comment: `ProgressDialog` is deprecated long ago its better if you don't use it . Create a Custom Dialog and set icon to `ImageView` .

Answer (score 1):

If your source file for gif/image is already in .gif format, then you can simply just write the below code:

```
Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.gif_file).into(imageView);
```

Comment: What if dont have imageView? Anyways to load image to setIcon or else create new layout with image view & display as progress dialog?.

Comment: you can use a layout inflater and add a ProgressDialgoue in your custom layout file. And you can add imageView in that custom layout file.